# how to drag a folders or files on an application?

Tags: launcher, application-development

I'd like to enable my users to drop folders (from nautilus) onto our custom applications (chromium based).

To my surprise I realize that users have little to no possibility to figure out the path to our applications. Of course, with exorbitant shell commands you could figure that out but only if you know how.

I am aware I could register somehow a custom context menu action for folders or file extensions but that's really not what I am looking for.

Any ideas?

There might be also different versions in different locations of applications, so writing hard-code paths into the user manual is not really an option.

Then I thought, people could drag that items onto the Launcher app entry/icon but it doesn't behave like other launcher toolbars.

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching in the sources and other topics here on this board:

No, Ubuntu is not designed for having simple drag and drop operations between File manager and applications, despite they copied a lot from OSX and others but just not the more important functionality nor implementing such things right.